# Changing Executable Path

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i built a cpp file in a ros project (after "catkin_make" command) the executable occurs in the path /devel/lib. But i want it to occur in /src . How can i change the built file's directory ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203017/changing-executable-path/) by [zuygar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21579/zuygar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2015-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-12**:
Why do you want that? It is unlikely that rosrun and other tools will work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would not recommend putting anything into `src`, but you can effect the output location of executables in CMake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556885/how-to-change-the-executable-output-directory-for-win32-builds-in-cmake

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1